# Gmail account disappeared and Google Play Store app not working on MXQ Pro Android TV Box

Tags: google-play-store, gmail, google-account

I have MXQ Pro 4K Android TV Box. The personal Gmail account disappeared and the Google Play Store won't allow sign-in/access.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.
What finally worked is:

Remove updates for Google Play Store and Google Play services (
Search on your computer for compatible .apk downloads for both apps (APKmirror.com has these files as download).
In my case (MXQ Pro 4k Amlogic S905) it was Android 7.1.2
Copy both .apk files to a SD card. Put it in the TV BOX and use APK Installer app to install these on the TV Box.
Then reboot.
Hope this will be helpfull